# ISBN 12 to 13 digit

Tags: python, python-3.x, isbn

I'm trying to return the ISBN-13 check digit from a 12-digit ISBN but have encountered a bizarre error.

Take the following as my 12-digit ISBN - 978311020318

Each digit is alternatively multiplied by 1 or 3.

9*1 + 7*3 + 8*1 + 3*3 + 1*1 + 1*3 + 0*1 + 2*3 + 0*1 + 3*3 + 1*1 + 8*3 = 91

91 % 10 = 1

10 - 1 = 9, which is our ISBN-13 check digit.

This is what I have so far...

```
def isbn_check_digit(isbn):
    s = 0
    for i, d in enumerate(isbn):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            s += int(d*1)
        else:
            s += int(d*3)
            print(s)
    return (10 - (s % 10))

print(isbn_check_digit("978311020318"))
```

Which outputs the following...

```
786
1127
1239
1461
1794
2683
7
```

I broke it up to see what was happening

```
    if i % 2 == 0:
        s += int(d*1)
        print(s)
    else:
        s += 0

9
17
18
18
18
19
1
```

Multiples of 1 are working fine, but why is it behaving strangely with multiples of 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, at the time that the expression `int(d * 3)` is evaluated, `d` is not a number — it's a string consisting of one character, which is a digit. As a result, "multiplying" it by 3 will repeat the digit three times: for instance, `3` will turn into `333`, rather than `9`.

You want to multiply by 3 *after* converting the string to an integer:

```
int(d) * 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes a whole lot of sense. I was thrown off by the fact that int(d * 1) worked.

Answer (score 0):

@dustwuff gave you the the cause, but another fix would be to use `map` and then convert your string to a list:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

def isbn_check_digit(isbn):
    number = list(map(int, isbn))
    check_sum = 0
    for i, d in grouper(2, number):
        check_sum += i*1 + d*3
    return 10 - check_sum % 10
```

`map` will apply the function to each member of the iterable. In this case, applying `int` will convert your string to a list of numbers.